# insert data into Microsoft SQL server using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to insert data into sql server using spark using the below Jdbc methods.

**Option 1:**

```
    prop.put("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
dataf.write.mode(org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode.Append).jdbc(url,table_name, prop)
```

Table is already created. Appending new data.Job Error-ed with the below exception

> Exception in thread "main"
>
> > com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: CREATE TABLE
> >     permission denied in database

Question is : `Why create table permission is required for appending the data?`

**Option2:**

```
    prop.put("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils.saveTable(dataf, url, table_name, prop)
```

Above command working from spark-shell. when the same is used in scala code and packaged with dependencies giving below exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)

I tried setting driver class-path and executor class-path and also --jars still no luck. Included sqljdbc4.jar in driver-classpath and --jars.
Copied sqljdbc4.jar to all worker nodes as well still no luck.

Any Ideas on this?

Comment: If something doesn't work after packaging then build definition and submit command would be useful.

Comment: I am using spark-submit and insertion to hive table is working fine.only problem is with sql server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Lot of searching and Testing, I found the answer. It might be useful for someone.

> Option 1: This is because of bug in spark 1.5.X. the same was resolved
>   in 1.6.x and later. Because of the bug, It always try to create a new
>   table.
>
> Option2: This causes  because , driver name on classpath given
>   priority than properties we are passing as argument. Workaround for
>   this is to create  connection and then invoke savetable.

```
 workaround if you are using spark 1.5.x or lower.
      JdbcUtils.createConnection(url, prop)
       JdbcUtils.saveTable()
```